# Почему не работает мой прогресс бар?

Tags: progress-bar, inno-setup

Нашел в интернете код:

```
[code]    
    var
      ProgressBar: TNewProgressBar;
    procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
    var
      i:Integer;
    begin
       If CurPageID=wpInstalling then
         begin
           ProgressBar := TNewProgressBar.Create(WizardForm);
           ProgressBar.Left := ScaleY(40);
           ProgressBar.Top := ScaleX(180);
           ProgressBar.Width := ScaleY(415);
           ProgressBar.Height := ScaleX(18);
           ProgressBar.Parent := WizardForm;
           ProgressBar.Position := 0; //указывает количество заполняемых секторов
        end;

    begin
       If CurPageID=wpFinished then ProgressBar.Hide
    end;
    end;
```

На странице отображается, но он не двигается. Почему? Что нужно ещё добавить, чтобы он стал двигаться при установке?

Comment: _чтобы он стал двигаться при установке?_ - не понятно, что имеется ввиду, так как прогресс бар бывает разных стилей, за что отвечает свойство `Style`, т.е. 
`TNewProgressBarStyle = (npbstNormal, npbstMarquee);`

Comment: Нет, мне нужен не стиль, а его движение по мере установки файлов.

Answer (score 1):

Это, конечно, не `Delphi`, но `InnoSetup` использует `ObjectPascal`. Компонент `TNewProgressBar` очень похож на `TProgressBar` в `Delphi`. Чтобы он "двигался", т.е. увеличивался по мере установки, вам необходимо изменять его свойство `Position` (обычно от 0 до 100, но возможны варианты). У вас же в коде вначале 0, затем вы его скрываете вообще после окончания действий на данном шаге установки (`If CurPageID=wpFinished`).

Comment: Да вот в том то и дело что что-то надо написать вместо нуля, только что? Вот в чем вопрос. А  (If CurPageID=wpFinished) скрывает прогресс-бар на финальной странице после завершения установки.

Comment: @ИванИваныч это зависит от того, КАК вы устроите установщик. Простой вариант: прогресс зависит от того, сколько окон мастера будет показано, тогда прогресс прибавляться с каждым новым окном. Либо более сложный (и логичный) вариант, когда прогресс зависит от того, сколько файлов уже скопировано/установлено. Читайте справку.